# how can i include JavaScript file in node.js for my ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am currently building a small website for my school project, I have searched through stackoverflow on how to include CSS files in node.js before and I have found the solution for it. However I have come across another problem and that is to include a javascript file in node.js.

This is my image slider.

[image: this is my image slider]

Answer (score 0):

Use nodejs **fs module** in your app.js 
to include public assets
following is the code of app.js

```
var fs  = require('fs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is misleading, you do not need the `fs` module in order to use the [`express.static` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Also, it would be helpful to explain the merits of using express.static to solve OP's issue